# Reusing CSS in JS

Tags: material-ui

I'm using Material UI for the first time and I'm starting to repeat a lot of CSS. I'm used to a global style sheet and reusing classes from that but I'm unsure how to do it with this framework.

I read through the docs and the only thing I can understand for my situation is to create a `createMuiTheme` and use it like this:

**Index.js**

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  fontFamily: {
    primary: "\"IM Fell DW Pica SC\", serif",
})

ReactDOM.render( 
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
 <CssBaseline />
 <App />
</MuiThemeProvider>,
document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**app.js**

```
const styles = theme => ({
  paragraph: {
   "fontFamily": theme.fontFamily.primary
  }
})

\\ DOM

<Typography variant="caption" gutterBottom className={paragraph}>
  Here is my paragraph text
</Typography>
```

Am I even using this correctly? To me, this doesn't cut down on a lot of code because if I create another a component that wants to use the same font family, I have to create the `paragraph` class again.

I have multiple components in separate files and find myself reusing a lot of simple styles like `textAlign: 'center'` and `fontWeight: 'bold'`

I thought about creating a separate JS file for the CSS and pulling from that but I'm not sure that's what Material UI was designed for. I'm thinking that I'm not using `createMuiTheme` to its full potential. Can anybody give me a simple solution to reusing some of these CSS styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restyle the component, and then it will be applied to all components inside the Theme wrapper, I did it like this:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const THEME = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    "fontFamily": "\"IM Fell DW Pica SC\", serif",
    "fontSize": 20,
    "lineHeight": 1.5,
    "letterSpacing": 0.32,
    useNextVariants: true,
    suppressDeprecationWarnings: true,
  },
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={THEME}>
        </YourComponentsThatHasThisFont>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In this case I changed the **typography** component form material-ui, so all the text that is written using their tag will be in this new font style.

If you want to override what your theme is setting, here's an example of an HOC that you can do.

```js
// imports

const styles = theme => ({
  text: {
    "&.override1": {
      fontSize: 15
    },
    "&.override2": {
      fontSize: 53,
      fontWeight: 700
    }
  }
});

const Text = ({ classes, children, override, ...rest }) => (
  <Typography
    classes={{ root: classes.text }}
    className={`${override}`}
    {...rest}
  >
    {children}
  </Typography>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(Text);
```

And you would just use that component just like you would a regular `Typography` component except you could also pass in things like `<Text variant="h2" override="override1">Hello World</Text>`

Comment: Okay thanks, but say I want another Typography tag with all the same styles except I want the font size to be 15 instead of 20. Or another tag with a different font-family...  Should I keep the repetitive styles in the MuiTheme and just create custom classes for each typography tag in each component i'm working on? Is that the only way around this?

Comment: Right that's one way to do it. Or if you need several different styles of Typography make an HOC that takes your own variant prop that overrides your theme's 20 with whatever corresponds to that variant.

Comment: @AnthonyZ Care to give me an example of what you mean by that?

Comment: Sure, I'll add an edit showing you something that you could do.